# Mailing queue in PHP

Tags: php, email, queue

I'm working on an application that will handle a lot of email sending, and I'm looking for a minimal email queue solution.

What the sending code will do, is get the "To", "From", "Subject", "Text", "Format" fields from the queue, generate the headers, and send the email. If the sent is not successful, it can be retried. I would like a priority system too, with, at least, two levels of priority.

I've been thinking and the ideas I got are these:

- MySQL: as everything else in the system goes through MySQL, I thought in using a MySQL table as a queue. The problem is that the sender must be always looking on the table, which causes a processor high load.
- Files: a queue can be done through XML files in a directory. This is bad for everything (performance, server life...)
- FIFOs: I've used FIFOs in C applications, but probably this is too low level for a high level application, and raw data is a bit harder to process (sizes, order of parameters...).

So I'm looking for ideas on how to do this email queue in an easy way. The system is done in PHP, and I'd like it to be in PHP, if there's solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If mysql is the bottleneck ... you send to many e-mails ;) ... What sould be faster than a database?

Comment: No, no. The problem is not MySQL. The problem is the email sender. It is an asynchronous system, and the sender has to know when it has work to do. The only way to do it with MySQL is performing queries periodically, which is a very CPU consuming task.

Comment: I have a mailqueue like that, BUT I do not save the text/content of the e-mail. If mails get too old (not send) there might be newer information available already. In my case 5-10 minutes = old. And this works perfectly for thousends of e-mails an hour.

Comment: Well, look into the queue, if there is still some data to send ... you call the database for other page request also ... and you know when you added a new row to the queue, so exactly then would be a good moment to walk the queue...

Comment: So you have a sender that every 2 seconds (to say something) checks the database for emails? Then probably I thought too much in this issue due to previous experiences in C.

Comment: No, as said, I know when there is at least one new e-mail to send, because I queue it to the database. Then I call my mailing script ... and additionally, I call it periodically "cron-like" each xy seconds. There is no way to avoid querying the database ... you could do long-polling, but this also requires the database to be queried each xy seconds. And, if I called the mailing script which tells me, there are xy messages left to send, then I directly call it again to send the next bunch of e-mails.

Comment: In my case it's not that time related. All important messages get send directly or with higher priority in the queue. All others could even been combinded into one e-mail, if a user receives more than one notification. So I send only one email with all information instead of many mini ones ... saves a lot of mails!

Answer (score 2):

I've developed an email queue system for PHP that does exactly what you're asking for, check it our here. https://github.com/tin-cat/emailqueue

Comment: As the original link seems to be dead, it seems that this is pointing to the correct repo: https://github.com/tin-cat/emailqueue

Comment: I've just released an Emailqueue Docker bundle that lets you set up a complete Emailqueue server in just a few minutes! It also now comes with API support and some other improvements, I think it might be really useful to you! Here it is: https://github.com/tin-cat/emailqueue-docker

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar to this before to send about 200,000 emails in a day. Since they weren't time critical, I generated them (with [Mail_Mime](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Mime)), and stored them all into a database, with [Mail_Queue](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Queue), sending them out with a shell script that kept re-running itself if the load average of the machine was OK.

Today, I'd do it with a Symfony-based system around [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) and [White October SwiftMailer DB Bundle](https://github.com/whiteoctober/WhiteOctoberSwiftMailerDBBundle).

To have it avoid the database (which isn't optimum, but it does Just Work) I would use the DBBundle as a base and instead have it go through a queue system, such as [Beanstalkd](http://kr.github.io/beanstalkd/) (it wouldn't be a big job to send it to a queue instead of a database table). The sending system can just delete the job if it decides it's 'too old'. Adding priorities to the queue job is also very easy - it's built right into Beanstalkd.

You could also elect to simply have the message in the queue be, "send user X an update email" - and the queue-runner goes to the original DB to assemble the email just before it is sent.